# Error calling C from Lua

Tags: c, lua

I tried [this example](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_lua_calls_c.htm) and had some problems with Lua:

```
icc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o power.so hellofunc.c -I/home/lukas/Workspace/Lua/LuaC -L/home/lukas/Workspace/Lua/LuaC/ -llua52
```

There were no problems compiling the `hellofunc.c` file, but when i try to run the Lua-File, i am getting the following error message:

```
lua LuaC.lua
lua: error loading module 'power' from file './power.so':
        liblua52.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        LuaC.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

LuaC.lua

```
require("power")
 print(square(1.414213598))
 print(cube(5))
```

The Lua libraries and headerfiles are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have installed Lua in your home directory instead of under a system folder (e.g. `/usr`), the loader does not know where to find the Lua dynamic library files when you run the program.

You can fix this by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to the folder containing the Lua dynamic library files, for example:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/lukas/Workspace/Lua/LuaC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but lua is installed under a system folder. I had some problems linking the libraries to compile the .c file and copied the two library files and the header files into this folder.

Comment: I've tried your solution and got another error. Some libraries where missing in the lib folder. Thank you very much!